# Ruby on Rails has_many :through Associations. Would this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, entity-relationship

I have a model Shop and a model Customer. A shop can have many customers and a Customer
can buy stuff from many shops. for this relationship I've created a join model 
ShopCustomers.

```
create_table :shop_customers do |t|
  t.integer :shop_id
  t.integer :customer_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

Models

```
 class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :shop_customers, :dependent => true
   has_many :customers, :through => shop_customers
   has_many :customers_groups
 end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :shop_customers, :dependent => true
   has_many :shops, :through => shop_customers
   belongs_to :customers_group_membership
end

class ShopCustomer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :shop
   belongs_to :customer
end
```

Shop owners want to be able to group customers and therefore I added another
model CustomersGroups.

```
class CustomersGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

And the Customers are added to a group through another join model.

```
create_table :customers_group_memberships do |t|
  t.integer :customers_group_id
  t.integer :customer_id
end

class CustomersGroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
  belongs_to :customers_group
end
```

Is this the correct way of doing such kind of a relationship or this is a recipe
for doom and am I missing something that would make this not to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the usual way of doing it. Have a look at the "has and belongs to many" association (AKA: HABTM). It will create the shops_customers join table for you and maintain it without you having to do it by hand.

here's a link to the apidock on HABTM: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: I didn't use habtm because I'm adding other fields in my join model. Josh Susser has a neat comparison [here](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off) of the two ways of doing this and pros and cons of each method. What I was actually asking was, I'm not sure if my through association is flawed or not.

Comment: Ok, well that was not in the question. I responded to what you actually asked, not what you intended ;) and the best way of doing what you have actually asked is to let rails do it for you.

Comment: If you intend these things to not actually be join-table models - then I'd recommend naming them as real models eg "Membership" or "CustomerRelationship"... rather than ShopCustomer - meaningful names make sense on real models.

Comment: To answer the question you intended to ask - yes, this will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Taryn, CustomerRelationship is a much better name for the model. and thank you for the code smell test.